# Port forward in google cloud

Tags: port-forwarding, ubuntu-18.04, minecraft

I've done quite a bit of googling with no luck so I decided I might as well ask a question specifically for me. If it's a duplicate then I haven't looked hard enough.

I'm trying to set up a minecraft server using a Google Cloud VM. It is running Ubuntu 18.04 and has enough hard drive space to run a server. It is being accessed using ssh on another computer in the network. After looking through error logs and google I discovered my issue, according to Tom Yan, was that I still had to port forward. Googling returns protocol forwarding, which Google Cloud definitely supports, but doing so returned no results. Following other guides didn't work. I have opened up port 25565 through the Google Cloud firewall as well as turned off UFW and still recieve the `FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!` response.

[More info on the server](https://superuser.com/questions/1514936/failed-to-bind-to-port-on-minecraft-server-on-a-google-cloud-server-running-ubun?noredirect=1#comment2292672_1514936)

Comment: Is `server-ip` set in your `server.properties` file?

Comment: It is but my issue is with port forwarding, not the server file. I detailed my `server.properties` file [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1514936/failed-to-bind-to-port-on-minecraft-server-on-a-google-cloud-server-running-ubun?noredirect=1#comment2292672_1514936), however, if it helps.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Cloud specifically, but that error is not related to port forwarding. Does your server have a separate public and private IP address?